# Change Rails session cookie domain without logging users out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise, single-sign-on

I'm using Rails 4.2.2 (with Devise 3.4.1) and am changing the cookie_store domain from www.boundless.dev to .boundless.dev in order to share the same session across all of our subdomains (single sign-on).

```
Boundless::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_boundless_session', domain: '.boundless.dev'
```

If I make this change alone. Existing logged-in users who return to the site will end up with 2 `_boundless_session` cookies, one with domain boundless.dev and the other with www.boundless.dev. Somehow this makes logging out impossible.

Is it possible to make this change without logging all users out of the site?

I thought that I'd be able to write a method as a `before_filter` in my ApplicationController to delete the session cookie and replace it with a new one at .boundless.dev, but it doesn't work, and I suspect it has something to do with the `remember_user_token` cookie.

```
def update_session_cookie_domain
  session_cookie = cookies['_boundless_session']
  cookies.delete('_boundless_session', domain: 'www.boundless.dev')
  cookies['_boundless_session'] = {
    value: session_cookie,
    domain: '.boundless.dev'
  }
end
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem I am facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by changing the cookie name used for the session.

So the original config was:

```
Boundless::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_boundless_session', domain: 'www.boundless.dev'
```

And I changed it to:

```
Boundless::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_boundless_session_NEW', domain: '.boundless.dev'
```

I expected this to log users out, but it doesn't for some reason that I don't quite understand.

Unfortunately, I've yet to find a way to clear the old `_boundless_session` cookie, but at least now I can log out after having my session cookie updated to the more general domain.

Comment: any idea on how this didn't log out the user?