# Rails - how to delete duplicate cookies across subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise, subdomain

Since I wanted to start supporting cross subdomain logins on my website. So I changed my session store config from

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
  key: '_my_app_session'
```

to

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
  key: '_my_app_session',
  domain: '.local.host', # I'm using *.local.host for 127.0.0.1
  tld_length: 2
```

After that, uses got 2 cookies with same name as list below, which caused uses could be logged out. I was using Devise, and it only delete `_my_app_session` under `.local.host`. So the user was kept signed in.

```
Name                Value           Domain
_my_app_session     abc             www.local.host
_my_app_session     xyz             .local.host
```

How can I delete both of the cookies?

Comment: Can you try with `domain: 'local.host'`?

Comment: But I want share cookies across subdomains, not just for `local.host`.

Comment: Yes, I suppose subdomains will share the same cookie in this case as well.

Comment: @31piy 4? Why? I also tried `local.host` but didn't work.

Comment: Please disregard my comment regarding TLD length.

Comment: Did you try with `domain: :all`?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I recommend you to change session key. Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31618130

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out `sidekiq/web` is causing this to us.

Our app is running on a subdomain and we have sessions configured to be shared across all subdomains so the cookie is created for `.domain.com`. But every time I access `/sidekiq` a new session is created for `sub.domain.com`.

To fix this in routes.rb I had to do this:

```
Sidekiq::Web.set :sessions, { domain: ".domain.com" }
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
```